# How to color svg:marker to the color of the line

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have the following ng template for generating arrow lines:

```
<ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
            <svg:g class="edge">
                <svg:marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4"
                    orient="auto">
                    <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head" />
                </svg:marker>
                <svg:path class="line" [attr.stroke]="link.color" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#arrow)">
                </svg:path>                    
            </svg:g>
        </ng-template>
```

How can I color the arrow-head to the color specified in the link.color variable?

Comment: Fill the marker's path with the same color (link.color)

Comment: Hi @enxaneta since the svg:marker is referenced by the path, only one instance exitsts hence applying the same color to all the arrow heads. I need to make the arrow head unique per path.

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle / codepen / codesandbox.io working example - more people can answer and even answer faster

Comment: Your marker id needs to be generated not fixed. At the moment you're creating multiple elements with the same id value and that's not allowed. And you need one marker per path, which I think you have already.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson do you know how to generate it. I tried something like this: <svg:marker [attr.id]="arrow + link.id"  and when referencing  <svg:path [attr.marker-end]="url(#arrow + link.id)"> but without luck

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to define two templates for the arrow head and reference from the line path accordingly.

```
<ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
                <svg:g class="edge">
                    <svg:marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" orient="auto">
                        <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head" />
                    </svg:marker>
                    <svg:marker id="arrow-sel" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" orient="auto">
                        <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head-sel" />
                    </svg:marker>
                    <svg:path class="line" [attr.stroke]="link.color" stroke-width="2" [attr.marker-end]="link.color === undefined ? 'url(#arrow)' : 'url(#arrow-sel)'">
                    </svg:path>           
                </svg:g>
            </ng-template>
```